# How can I apply Qulice formatting rules?

Tags: java, qulice

In one of my previous projects we had spotless for code style. And it had goal spotlessApply (which  changed all formatting issues).

For current project we use Qulice.
Do you know whether it has quliceApply? Or how can I fix formatting by running a task?

I checked on official website [www.qulice.com](http://www.qulice.com) but didn't find.
I don't want to read dozens of formatting warnings and then apply it manually one by one.